# read a table in controller (laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I wanted to add tags to my posts. (laravel blog)

so I created a table with two columns first one was post_id and the second was tag_id and both these columns were foreign keys. now I want to show the tags for each post and I don't know how to get the table information.

this is my migration file

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

so how do I get the **post_tag** table information in my **postController** to show them in view?

```
    public function getHomeIndex(){
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(9);

        $tags = ??????


        return view('blog.index', ['posts' => $posts], 'tags' => $tags);
    }
```

or maybe I'm doing it wrong and there is a better way to send the tags in veiw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Post model define `tag` relation

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'post_tag');
}
```

In controller use

```
public function getHomeIndex()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->with('tags')->paginate(9);
    return view('blog.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

In view

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    // post data here 
    @foreach($post->tags as $tag)
        // $tag related data here
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```